# flutter firebase notifications not working as expected on android phone

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not able to receive notifications on my android emulator.

Here is the message I see in the terminal::

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 8541): broadcast received for message
```

So I am getting the message, but I cant do anything with it?

I am testing the notifications by going to firebase and creating a dummy message ( see image attached )

[image: Firebase messaging center]

here is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: ijob_clone_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  image_cropper: ^3.0.0
  fluttericon: ^2.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.3
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  file_picker: ^5.2.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  firebase_messaging: ^14.0.3
  





  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_place: ^0.4.7


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.2
  bloc: ^8.1.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^10.0.3
  overlay_support: ^2.0.1
 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images/

  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
```

here is my build.gradle file ( android > app > build.gradle )

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is (android > app > src build.gradle)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
   
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "na.mynotes"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}


// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
```

Comment: it happens most of the time on emulators. you should be using a real device.

Comment: Remember that Notification messages which arrive while the application is in the foreground will not display a visible notification by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have to act on the data received to present it.

You could use the package `flutter_local_notifications` to customize everything.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications